# unity animation won't play unless input key is held

Tags: unity, animation

The code is simple. If the player presses the right arrow key, one animation clip plays. If the left arrow key, another clip plays, etc. However, the clip doesnt play fully unless the input key is held continuously. The second you release it, the second the clip stops playing. I think it's something to do with update() and the input not being remembered over next frame.

The code is simple:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class animatorcontroller_Logic : MonoBehaviour 
{

    Animator anim;

    enum MovementState
    {
        Idle = 0,
        run = 1,
        walk = 2,
    }

    MovementState currentMovementState;

    void Start () 
    {
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    void Update () 
    {

        if(Input.GetButton("right")) 
        {
            currentMovementState = MovementState.run;

        }

        else if(Input.GetButton("left")) 
        {
            currentMovementState = MovementState.walk;

        }

        else
        {
            currentMovementState = MovementState.Idle;    //set movement state to idle
        }


        anim.SetInteger("MovementState", (int)currentMovementState);    

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the `Update()` call immediately following releasing the key, your `else` clause sets `currentMovementState = MovementState.Idle`. This stops the walk animation, I presume.

Comment: How can I fix this? I am still an amateur coder.

Comment: Remove the `else` clause, and it will stop doing this. How you deal with these issues depends on how your game is set up, and is beyond the scope of an answer to your question.

Comment: thing is if I remove else, it wont go back to idle as the parameter will remain set at 1 and it will keep animating the current clip forever.

Comment: have the walk cycle animation dispatch an event in the loop when it finishes. check for idlenss then.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just need to set the transition condition to Exit Time = 0.95 in the state machine instead. This ensures the animation plays fully before going back to idle.